# Find all elements that are lesser than or equal to the value

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new in c# and I have an array like this:

```
int[] cost = new int[] {10, 15, 20, 30, 50};
```

What is the simplest code to find/get all values that are lesser than or equal to the value?

The given value is 29, would return 20, 15, and 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one of the simplest things you can do for this:

```
var resultArray = cost.Where(item => item <= 29).ToArray();
```

Here's another:

```
var resultArray = Array.FindAll(cost, item => item <= 29);
```

1. The first option uses an extension methods named `Where` that operates on `IEnumerable`, which arrays implement.  `IEnumerable` is an interface for a sequence of elements that can be stepped through one after the other.
2. The second option uses `FindAll`, which is actually built in to the `Array` class.

The `item => item <= 29` stuff is `lambda notation`.  It's a highly concise way of defining a function on the spot.

This way of writing an anonymous function on the spot is saying

- `Where` or `FindAll` each receive an argument that is an anonymous function, and we will define that argument that is an anonymous function right here in the actual call to `Where()` or `FindAll()`.
- The anonymous function itself receives as its own one argument an element, which we'll call `item` (the name could be anything, it could also be `x`). This item is an individual element of the `Array` (or `IEnumerable`)--elements being `int`s in this case--which the compiler infers. The name of the function argument is left of the `=>`
- the function body is right of the `=>`.  (Read `=>` as "this is a function where the argument `item` goes to the body right of the `=>` ") The body is an expression that evaulates to a `Boolean` `true` or a `false`, so the return value of the function is a `Boolean`.

So, essentially `item => item <= 29` is the same as declaring a function like the below, but it's much more concise and can be easily used as an argument to another function. Here's the long way of declaring such a function, so you can see that the lambda way of writing it is much more concise:

```
Boolean int func(int x)
{
    if (x<=29) {
        return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

- the `Where` or `Array.FindAll` functions call the lambda function on each element in the `Array` or `IEnumerable` and return (yield) back only those items where the lambda function returns true.

**Update**

Looks like you edited the original question to remove a reference to finding indexes, so the below is no longer relevant (the above stuff finds values of elements, not indexes of elements).  But the below shows how to find both values and indexes of the array elements that satisfy the condition:

You mentioned indexes.  This version also finds the indexes of the original array (not just the elements) that satisfy the criterion:

```
List<int> indexesInvolved = new List<int>();
var resultArray = cost.Where((item, index) =>
    { 
        if (item <= 29) {
            indexesInvolved.Add(index);
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        } 
    }
 ).ToArray();
var foundIndexArray = indexesInvolved.ToArray();
```

Comment: Added tracking of the indexes.

Comment: Great answer. The last bit of code can be more readable imo as `if (item > 29) return false; indexesInvolved.Add(index); return true;`

Comment: the first code gives me only 1 element , 20
(not 20, 15, 10) and your second code gives me 1 index too

Comment: @Rapoix no, it gives all three elements. `.Where()` will filter out all items that don't match the condition—`item <= 29`. Are you sure you've copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't change the logic.  Not sure why you initially only got one element.

Comment: Hm, maybe you can post your whole code.  I just re-ran it and it gives me three elements.

Comment: `private void test()
        {
            int money = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            List<int> indexesInvolved = new List<int>();
            var resultArray = costR.Where((item, index) => { if (item <= money) { indexesInvolved.Add(index); return true; } else { return false; } }).ToArray();
            var fIndex = indexesInvolved.ToArray();

            //testing
            foreach (int test in fIndex)
            {
                restaurantA.Text = restN[test];
            }
            
        }`
i have a textfield where user put money

Comment: What's in `costR` when `test()` is run. And what value is in `textBox1` (i.e. what is is in `money`)

Comment: `int[] costR = new int[] { 100, 120, 200, 300, 360, 400, 500, 600 };`
The `textBox1` is ,yeah, a text field where users put money (they put like this 306 ) . I'm focusing at your last code

Comment: Try this just as a proof of concept:`static void  test()
{
    int money = 29;
    int[] costR = new int[] { 10, 15, 20, 30, 50 };
    List<int> indexesInvolved = new List<int>();
    var resultArray = costR.Where((item, index) =>
    {
        if (item <= 29)
        {
            indexesInvolved.Add(index);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
     ).ToArray();
    var fIndex = indexesInvolved.ToArray();
}`

Comment: Even the proof of concept that I posted with the original values (29 for criterion and 10,15,20,30,50 in the array?)

Comment: Yes, `static void test() { int money = 29; int[] costR = new int[] { 10, 15, 20, 30, 50 }; List<int> indexesInvolved = new List<int>(); var resultArray = costR.Where((item, index) => { if (item <= 29) { indexesInvolved.Add(index); return true; } else { return false; } } ).ToArray(); var fIndex = indexesInvolved.ToArray(); }`

Comment: oh should i add static to my method?

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry I didn't understand your question at first.  No, the static shouldn't matter. That comes from how I used the method in a Console Application to test it.  So no, you don't need to add static.

Comment: i used windows application, and mine shows a single index so the output is `2`, not `0 1 2` .. should i show you the screen shot and the whole code?

Comment: Go ahead with screen shot, sure.

Comment: oh wait, i tried your code in console app and it worked! have you tried it in the windows app? my whole code: http://pastebin.com/Vq3Ldk07

Comment: I didn't have all the code (the form and conrols), so I stripped down your code from pastebin and had the test_click fire findRestaurants in a Windows forms application. With "306" in textBox1, it found four, which is correct.  Not sure what's different.  Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/ihPKba7j