# C# - How to use operator for numbers in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an int array that store age values. I want to print all the values in the array which are above or eqaul to 18.

```
int[] age = new int[] { 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30 };
      
foreach(int item in age)
{

}
```

I tried something like this but didn't work.

```
int[] age = new int[] { 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30 };
int targetAge = 18;
int findedAge = Array.FindIndex(age, age => age == targetAge);

if (age>= targetAge)
{
    foreach (int item in age)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: FindIndex returns the index of the first element that's equal to targetAge(18).
Also, even if you retrieve this value that's wrong you are not using it, so it is useless. You are also comparing an array (age) to an integer. This operation can't be done because the two objects cannot be compared, it's like comparing apple and pears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter the array you can do this:

```
var resultArray = age.Where(item => item >= 18).ToArray();
```

or use the FindAll:

```
var resultArray = Array.FindAll(age, item => item >= 18);
```

The first option uses an extension methods named Where that operates on IEnumerable, which arrays implement. IEnumerable is an interface for a sequence of elements that can be stepped through one after the other.

The second option uses FindAll, which is actually built in to the Array class.

For more info you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885702/6895130).

Comment: You'll need `using System.Linq;` for this to work.

Comment: Your solution is surely correct, but I like more the one provided by @tymtam because it provides better performance and less memory usage (I find no difference in terms of readability)

Comment: @MatteoUmili Removing `.ToArray` would reduce memory usage

Comment: Yeah, `.ToArray()` is abundant here if the only thing OP needs to do is `foreach` and `WriteLine`.

Answer (score 2):

You are so close!

```
foreach (int item in age)
{
    if (item>= targetAge)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two changes here: 
1. You have `if` outside of `foreach` and that's incorrect. 
2. It's `if (item >= `, not `if (age>= `

Comment: @IndieDev if the code you wrote is the real one then age is an `int[]`, so item must be an `int`. You also wrote that targetAge is an int so the code wrote by @tymtam is correct